# Session logging of "\$Echo" and "\$Output" in Mathematica 10

Tags: front-end, scripting

I have difficulties with session logging and Mathematica 10. In previous versions, you could simply use `AppendTo[$Echo, logfile]` and `AppendTo[$Output, logfile]`.

In Mathematica 10, appending to `$Echo` only works for cells in raw input format, as stated in the [reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Echo.html).

Appending to `$Output` seems not working. Log file is always empty.

My questions:

a) How can I force all input cells to be in "raw input format", without converting the cells by the menu?

b) What's wrong with my `AppendTo[$Output]`?

```
oldout = $Output;
logfile = OpenWrite[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "math.log"}],
    FormatType -> InputForm];
AppendTo[$Output, logfile];
AppendTo[$Echo, logfile];
First@logfile

(* tests, $Echo works, if cell is converted to raw input format *)
2+2
Expand[(a + b)^3]
Factor[z^5 - 1]
N[Pi, 24]
Close[logfile];
$Echo={};
$Output = oldout;
FilePrint[First@logfile]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Wolfram Language Script this is a new thing...

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html

Put your code in a .wl plain text file:

```
Solve[x^2+3x+2==0,x]


2+2
Expand[(a+b)^3]
Factor[z^5-1]
N[Pi,24]
7/0
```

and then runs like this:

```
> wolframscript -print all -file s1.wl
{{x -> -2}, {x -> -1}}
4
a^3 + 3*a^2*b + 3*a*b^2 + b^3
(-1 + z)*(1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4)
3.1
41592                                 1
Power::infy: Infinite expression - encountered.
                                 06
5358979323846264338327950288582`24.
ComplexInfinity
```